# $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ connected or disconnected?

Tags: general-topology

Let
\begin{align*}
    A & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{Q} \}, \\
    B & = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; \text{at least one of $x, y$ is rational} \}.
  \end{align*}
Is the space $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ connected? Is the space $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ connected? Prove your assertions.

**My attempt**:

$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is disconnected, but I don't know how to show that while $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ is connected because for every rational number $a$, $\{a\} \times \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R} \times \{a\}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$. Is it right? And how can I show that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is not connected?

Comment: You have $A \subset B$, dude!

Comment: To show the first is disconnected find two open sets that are disjoint and cover $A$. I recommend two open half-planes.

Comment: Don't confuse $\mathbb R^2 \setminus B$ with $B$ (and similarly with $A$). No point  $(a, y)$ where $a$ is rational is in $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb R^2 \setminus A$ is connected (in fact, path connected). Notice that $$\mathbb R^2 \setminus A = \{(x,y) \, : \, \text{ at least one of } x,y \text{ is irrational}\}.$$ Take two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus A$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $x_1$ is irrational (if not, then $y_1$ is irrational, and we can swap the coordinates essentially "transposing" $\mathbb R^2$ and the same argument goes through). Since $x_1$ is irrational, the entire line $\{(x_1,y)\}_{y \in \mathbb R}$ is in $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$.

If $y_2$ is irrational, then the entire line $\{(x,y_2)\}_{x \in \mathbb R}$ is in $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$. Travel the path $$(x_1,y_1) \to (x_1,y_2) \to (x_2,y_2)$$ and you have found a path that connects the two points while staying in the set.

If instead $x_2$ is irrational, then the entire line  $\{(x_2,y)\}_{y \in \mathbb R}$ is in $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$. Travel the path $$(x_1,y_1) \to (x_1,\sqrt 2) \to (x_2,\sqrt 2)\to (x_2,y_2)$$ and you have found a path that connects the two points while staying in the set.

The set $\mathbb R^2 \setminus B$ is disconnected. Note that $$\mathbb R^2 \setminus B = \{(x,y) \, : \, \text{ both } x,y \text{ are irrational}\}.$$ Thus for example, no point on the line $\{(x,0)\}_{x\in\mathbb R}$ is in $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$, which shows that if we define $$\mathbb R^2_+ = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \, : \, y > 0\} \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,\,\, \mathbb R^2_- = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \, : \, y < 0\},$$ then we have two disjoint open sets with $\mathbb R^2 \setminus B \subset \mathbb R^2_+ \cup \mathbb R^2_-$.